# "そのことですか" is this some kind of expression?

Tags: questions, particle-か

> よかった。。。って言っていいもんかな

I wonder if it's alright to say "I'm glad"

> 何がです?

About what?

> お前さんは何年追いかけた敵を討ったじゃない

You didn't kill the enemy that you chased for years (or you killed the enemy you have been chasing for years,didn't you)

> そのことですか

> あんまり嬉しそうじゃないね. ほんと死んでほしくなかったかい?

You don't look too happy. You didn't want him to die?

What does そのことですか here mean? Some そのことですかわからない maybe?

I also took as 討ったじゃない as "You didn't kill" but could it be "You felled him, didn't you"? I guess the confusing is because he didn't kill him himself but he still died.

Comment: Yes it's a phrase literally meaning "that sort of thing" but people say it in the same way we would say "really?" in response to information.「そういうこと?」I also hear a lot from my friends used in the same way.
It's a way to acknowledge, like how sundowner said. In this example i think it translates well to **"is that so"**

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can think of, *verb(ta-form)* + じゃない always means *isn't it?/didn't you* etc. When it is used as *noun + じゃない*, it can be ambiguous as in これは大発見じゃない = this is quite a discovery, isn't it? / this is not (worth being called) a discovery.

So 討ったじゃない means *you killed the enemy, didn't you?*. そのことですか is an acknowledgment for understanding what the other means.

- 何がです? - About what?
- お前さんは何年追いかけた敵を討ったじゃない - You killed the guy
- そのことですか - (Ah, did you mean) that thing.

Comment: The one exception I can think of is a particular use of じゃない, like 「『やっちゃった』じゃない！」 'Don't say "oops, I did it"!'